# Probability - Drawing lots

Tags: probability

If I have a pool of 55 numbers, and I make 5 draws without replacement, what are the chances I get the number 20 (or any number, assuming only one number strikes) ?

Comment: What are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: @Lovsovs It feels like its 5/55, but it can't be that simple I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Consider the probability of the complement: 
$\frac{54\cdot 53 \cdot 52\cdot 51 \cdot 50}{55\cdot 54\cdot 53 \cdot 52\cdot 51}$ (without replacement)
or $\left(\frac{54}{55}\right)^5$ (with replacement).

Comment: This is without replacement.

Comment: @Lovsovs Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to $1$ minus the probability that you *won't* draw your number ($20$).

In the first draw there is a $\frac{54}{55}$ probability that you don't draw the $20$. In the second draw, there is a $\frac{53}{54}$ probability, and so on. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Alright, got it, thank you!